# Sharing a USB printer with IPP (internet printing protocol)?

Tags: linux, printer, share, cups

I have a small server (Linux 2.6.x) with one dedicated USB port only for printers. And I have been asked to configure a software to automatically share via IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) any printer connected to that port.

I  need a really lightweight solution, as it's a kind of an embedded server, so memory is not a luxury at all.

Thanks

Comment: What's the question? If you've configured a printer using cups then you're already sharing it via IPP - you may need to amend the access controls though.

Comment: No, I haven't done anything with cups. That's why I am asking. I don't know if CUPS is a good solution or not. But as I said, is like an embedded linux server, so cups may be too big.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but CUPS is the only thing out there for Linux right now that supports what you said you want to do. Big or small, it's all you've got - as far as software goes.

If you can't use CUPS, go buy [a cheap print server](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007830%20600014444&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&SrchInDesc=IPP&Page=1&PageSize=20) (or an expensive one) that supports IPP and plug the printer into that.

Answer (score -3):

p910nd
p910nd.sourceforge.net/

p910nd is a small printer daemon intended for diskless workstations and low-resource situations.  Memory and load are negligible.

This is an excellent lightweight solution for embedded systems.

Comment: p910nd is useful software. But it doesn't do what @fazineroso wants.